# firebase once() gives permission error, though ref() succeeds

Tags: permissions, firebase

The goal:  scan firebase data and delete items older than a given time.

The problem:  the query generates a permissions error, though other read operations are allowed.  Yet the problem seems to be the .read rule, since when it's taken out, everything works.

I authenticate using a token with "username" and "dataClass" embedded.  Authentication normally works fine, and subscribed clients are receiving updates.  Debugging log and examining the auth() payload show that the "username" and "dataClass" are correctly embedded in the token and correctly extracted by Firebase.

However, trying to use once() to get a subset of data older than a certain age generates a permission error.  I can see the data location using ref(), however, with no error.  Why does ref() work and a query doesn't?  Possible basic misunderstanding:  does a query return a copy of data, as it would in a SQL database, or does it return pointers to the data?

Here's the code, followed by the rules being used.  Thanks mucho.

```
var Firebase = require('firebase');
Firebase.enableLogging(true, true);

// auth token is passed in as an argument
var token;
process.argv.forEach(function(val, index, array) {if (index==2) {token=val;} });

var oneHourAgo=(new Date).getTime() - (minutes*60000);

var fb=new Firebase("https://<mysite>.firebaseio.com/changeMessages");
connect2Firebase(fb,token);


function connect2Firebase(firebase,authToken) {
  firebase.auth(authToken, function(error,payload) {
    if(error) {
      console.log("Login Failed!", error);
    } else {
      console.log("Login Succeeded!");
      console.log(payload);
      doSomething();
    }
  });
}


function doSomething() {
  // THIS GIVES PERMISSION ERROR
  fb.endAt(oneHourAgo).once('value', function(ss) { console.log(ss.val()); });

  // THIS WORKS
  //console.log(fb.endAt(oneHourAgo).ref().toString());
}


// THE RULES.  Changing to ".read":true makes it work.
{
  "rules": {
    "changeMessages": {
      "$dataClass": {
      ".read": "auth.dataClass == $dataClass && auth.username == 'admin'",
      ".write": "auth.username == 'admin'"
  }
}
```

}
}

Comment: .ref() is a local op (it doesn't actually involve any connection to the server) and simply creates a new "reference" to a path on the server, so this would never cause a permissions error. To clarify, are you saying this query works if you change the date value passed into endAt()?

Comment: Not exactly.  Right now all the data is over an hour old, so all of it should be selected.  But none of it is, in fact, it always gives a permission error no matter what date value is passed into endAt().

Comment: Using the simulator, the rules work as expected and read is accepted with given values in auth JSON. With the actual program, debug shows that the same values are passed in auth(), yet "once('value'..." returns "permission denied". There's something I'm not understanding about once().  Could it be that it's asynchronous?  Also, to be clear, I don't want to just download a copy of data to the client, I ultimately want to delete data over an hour old on the Firebase server.

Comment: @kato, How about another approach:  instead of writing a separate server program (I'm doing this in Node.js) to delete old firebase data, set up a simple event when the client connects:        `firebaseRef.endAt(timestampOneHourAgo).on("child_added", function(snap) {snap.ref().remove();}`
Adding events like this, even thousands of them, is supposed to be efficient.  However, remove() generates a "child_added" event, which is a circular reference and could cause a hang.  Setting the event with once() won't keep the cleanup going.  How to get around the circular reference?

Comment: If the op works in simulator but not on the client, then the auth tokens cannot be the same. .once() is async but your example above works fine as an async event. your example security rules have a missing } as written; are they accurate? You can add debug: true to the "options" part of your token (second argument) to see output similar to simulator on the client.

Comment: Got this resolved.  For the benefit of others, the problems with rules arose from a misunderstanding about defaults and scope of rules.  I assumed a missing rule at a given level defaults to the system default of "write":true.  The new rule compiler of Firebase may help with problems such as this.  Secondly, @kato pointed me to his example code at [https://gist.github.com/katowulf/b2817d3139f2632247a6]  which uses the .name() operator to navigate through children for which you don't the name.